# filter_var($variable, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) always producing false

Tags: php

I am trying to using email validation on my registration page, but the `if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)` is always returning false even for a legitimate email address such as: bob.smith@hotmail.com

PHP Code:

```
    <?php require 'Assets/Connections/Connections.php';

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Register'])) 
  {
        //whether the firstname is blank
        if ($_POST['First_Name'] == '') 
    {
      $_SESSION['First_NameErr'] = "First Name is required.";
    }
    //whether the lastname is blank
    if ($_POST['Last_Name'] == '') 
    {
      $_SESSION['Last_NameErr'] = "Last Name is required.";
    }
    //whether the email is blank
    if($_POST['Email'] == '')
    {
      $_SESSION['EmailErr1'] = "E-mail is required.";
    }
    else
    {
      //whether the email format is correct
        if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
      {
        // Return Success - Valid Email
        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user 
                WHERE email = '$Email'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) 
                  or die(mysqli_error());
       if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
        {
        $_SESSION['EmailErr2'] = "This Email is already used.";
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // Return Error - Invalid Email
        $_SESSION['EmailErr3'] = "Your email is not valid.";
      }
    }
    //whether the password is blank
    if($_POST['Password'] == '')
    {
    $_SESSION['PasswordErr'] = "Password is required.";
    }
    //if an error is created, the user is re-directed to a blank registration form
    if(isset($_SESSION['First_NameErr']) || isset($_SESSION['Last_NameErr']) || isset($_SESSION['EmailErr1']) || isset($_SESSION['EmailErr2']) || isset($_SESSION['EmailErr3']) || isset($_SESSION['PasswordErr']))
    {
      echo "Error";
      var_dump(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    #header("Location: Register.php");
    #exit;
    }
    else
    {
    $FName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['First_Name']);
    $LName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Last_Name']);
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
    $PW = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Password']);
    $StorePassword = password_hash($PW, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO user (Fname, Lname, Email, Password)
                        Values('$FName', '$LName', '$Email', '$StorePassword')") 
                        or die(mysqli_error());

    header('Location: LogIn.php');
    die();
    }
  }
?>
```

Html form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="Assets/CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Assets/CSS/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header"></div>
  <div class="Menu">
    <div id="Menu">
      <nav>
        <ul class="cssmenu">
          <li><a href="FrontPage.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="LogIn.php">LogIn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CentreBody">
    <form id="RegisterForm" name="RegisterForm" method="post">
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="text" name="First_Name" required="required" class="TField" id="First_Name" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="text" name="Last_Name" required="required" class="TField" id="Last_Name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="email" name="Email" required="required" class="TField" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="password" name="Password" required="required" class="TField" id="Password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="FormElement">
        <input type="submit" name="Register" class="button" id="Register" value="Register">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="Footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try trimming `$_POST['Email']` during the test, like `filter_var(trim($_POST['Email']l), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: Do `echo $_POST['Email'];` and see what it is showing

Comment: check for errors. we don't know what the HTML form looks like, or if you started the session.

Comment: I would suggest to send an email with an activation link to the person registering on your page, that way you know the email is valid and exists.

Comment: @JayBlanchard adding trimming didn't work, the same outcome occurred; error.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the var_dump shows: `string 'bob.smith@hotmail.com' (length=21)`. I am assuming an echo would show the same?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the session is started at the top of the page, and the html form is standard (see updated OP).

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your OP to add anything new.

Comment: Tested with bob.smith@hotmail.com; unable to reproduce. If you're using some JS/JQuery for additional validation, show it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am not using any JS/JQuery. However I will add my whole page to see if the issue lies outside of area I included. Check OP.

Comment: This is what I used for code to test with: `if(isset($_POST['Register']))
    {

if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false)
      {

echo "Valid";

}

else{
echo "Not valid";
}


}` - Try that. Then, start adding in the rest of your code. When something breaks, you'll know what to go after.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It appears the error check at the bottom produces `echo "Error";` if any of the previous if statements results were empty or invalid, even though its showing `valid`. If I remove `isset($_SESSION['EmailErr3'])` the error stops, as that error is set if the `filter_var !== false.` Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I change the first line. 
and also I add the trim function to the $_POST['Email']
$_POST['Email'] = trim($_POST['Email']);

The validation of the email is Ok, the only way that could fail is if the email have some space. like "bob.smith@hotmail.com < space >"

I hope this could help!

```
<?php


#if($_POST['Email'] == ''){
if(!empty($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Email'])){
    $_SESSION['EmailErr1'] = "E-mail is required.";
}else{
    //whether the email format is correct
    $_POST['Email'] = trim($_POST['Email']);

    if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== False){
        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$Email'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0){
            $_SESSION['EmailErr2'] = "This Email is already used.";
        }
    }else{
    // Return Error - Invalid Email
        $_SESSION['EmailErr3'] = "Your email is not valid.";
    }
}



//if an error is created, the user is re-directed to a blank registration form
if(isset($_SESSION['EmailErr1']) || isset($_SESSION['EmailErr2']) || isset($_SESSION['EmailErr3'])){
    echo "Error";
    var_dump(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
}else{

    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Email']);
    INSERT into table....
}

?>
```

Comment: Your logic is incorrect in the first line, you can just say `if(empty($_POST['Email']))` You're testing to make sure it is populated when the OP is checking to see if it isn't.